# How to rename listoftodos

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, todonotes

I'm using french babel.

How could I rename `\listoftodos` ?

I've tried `\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\listoftodos}{Relevé des remarques}}` but it doesn't work

Best regards,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `todonotes` package supports other languages, it doesn't seem to use the regular `babel` interface.  Instead you need to set the name in the following way:

```
\makeatletter
\@todonotes@SetTodoListName{Relevé des remarques}
\makeatother
```

Here's a complete example: (this is the kind of example that is helpful to add when you ask a new question.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\@todonotes@SetTodoListName{Relevé des remarques}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\section{A section}
Some text \todo{Add something here} in the document.  

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @loruyza You should unaccept my answer and accept Fran's which is simpler. Then I can delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\listoftodos[Relev\'e des remarques]
\section{A section}
Some text \todo{Add something here} in the document.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: :) This is a much better answer. I should follow my own advice. *But that's where you're wrong. As we know from the site, you just ask your question here without reading the documentation, and them someone who has read it will tell you what's in the documentation.* https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=41010797#41010797